# Azure AD B2C with Spring 4

Tags: spring, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have Spring application with Spring Security version 3.2.5 and spring version 4.3.7.

I want to remove the old fashioned login page and integrate it with Azure AD B2C. For the B2C part, I have the B2C tenant and necessary policies in place. I tried finding something on this for Spring, but all the examples and samples I found were based on spring boot.

Is it feasible to achieve B2C authentication & authorization integration with Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no proper [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/) where we have entire information for Spring to integrate with Azure AD B2C.

This [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-b2c-web-sample#a-java-web-appplication-with-azure-ad-b2c) demonstrates a Java web application that is secured using Azure AD B2C. And this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-java-servlet-webapp-authentication) demonstrates a Java Servlet webapp that signs in users with Azure AD B2C. You could refer to them.